# Why is logout moved to my profile page?

Tags: discussion, logout

I feel that the logout link on top of page was a reasonably good place to have it rather than in the user profile page. I would prefer it back on top of the page.

However I would like to know if there is any specific reason to move the logout link to profile page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We moved it because

1. It's the least used item on the header as measured by HTTP requests.
2. We need more room on the header, as we've added SE global nav, chat, meta, and two kinds of flags there. For people with "long" names like Rebecca Chernoff it was causing the header to wrap.

The link was moved to your user page, or you can always type in `/users/logout` in the address bar.

Edit - the link is not on the user page any more, it's now located on the mouse-over pop-down menu available when you hover the mouse over your name in the header.

Comment: @Jeff - Thanks, but would this not create more confusion on the site for users to first understand where to find logout option? If logout is taking lot of header space, then it can probably be modified to show up as a small icon after FAQ link right?

Comment: @sachin our actual data shows this link is used hardly at all. There's no way it needs to be a top-level menu item.

Comment: @Jeff - Hmmm... I think most users just close their browsers instead of logging out probably.

Comment: @sachin I think you understand correctly. I also don't normally log out of gmail or facebook.

Comment: @Jeff I think the standard solution to this problem is to have the user name be a menu (or a little arrow next to it) with "logout" as one option (see Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn)

Comment: @david regardless, it's still two clicks, exactly the same as the way we have it now

Comment: @Jeff: It's a question of discoverability. If it's in an unusual place, casual users of the site won't find it.

Comment: Those are good, valid reasons for rearranging the UI, but IMO, this is a very confusing and unexpected solution. Rollback and rethink, please?

Comment: @Jeff:  Reducing it to clicks simplifies too far.  It's really 2 clicks vs. 2 clicks+page refresh+find the link.

Comment: Speaking as a very recent victim/new user, the hidden logout (which doesn't actually work, but I guess that's a different thread) was a Really Bad Idea (TM). The d*** thing kept logging me back in as my sister, necessitating yet *another* dig through however many clicks and pages to find the darn thing. Hiding logout like this would only be justified if the site had an auto-logoff policy (as in, if closing the browser had the same effect as logging out, then we wouldn't need the button).

Comment: @jpm simply click "log out everywhere" on the logout page to clear HTML 5 local storage. Also, you're kind of doing it wrong -- you should log in as different users in the operating system, or at the *very least* use different web browsers (she uses Firefox, you use Chrome). You're going to have problems all over the web if you subvert the operating system's concept of user isolation.

Comment: @Jeff: we've been doing things this way for decades. This is the VERY FIRST time we've had any trouble whatsoever. Every other login-type site we use is fully capable of logging *out*. That argues for the problem being with the site, not with our way of browsing.

Comment: @Jeff: oh, and our current theory is that part of the problem was that we were both on (on different computers, in different counties!) at the same time. Do you propose to require everyone to, I don't know, only ever use a single computer everywhere?

Comment: @jpm I don't know how many other ways to say this: click the log out everywhere button, it does what you want. Feel free to email me directly if you need step by step instructions.

Comment: @Jeff - The new feature where the logout appears in dropdown on top header seems superb. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff please re-review that click data down the road, if the new stuff is "less" used than the logout link was, then think about bringing it back

Comment: @Jeff, considering the link isn't on the user page any more, it's /only/ on the mouse over, could you explain why it couldn't be re-introduced on the user page at lease? Just /somewhere/ where you can SEE the link when you're searching for it.